# Is this map onto?

Tags: linear-algebra

Define a map from $\Bbb R^4\to \Bbb R^3$ by $\left( x,y,z,t\right)\rightarrow (x-t,z-y,x-2y+2z-t)$

Is this map onto?

I understand the definition of Surjectivity (i.e. onto) but I am having a little difficulty applying it to this question.

Comment: You need to specify domain and codomain of the map. Assuming that it is $\Bbb{R}^4 \to \Bbb{R}^3$, then this is a linear map. Compute its matrix, and try to compute the rank of the matrix.

Comment: What would the rank have to do with weather or not its surjective ?

Comment: The map is linear so the map is onto iff the rank is 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the coordinates of the three outputs are $(u,v,w)$ note that $w=u+2v.$ So it isn't onto.

I meant $u=x-t,\ v=z-y,\ w=x-2y+2z-t.$ above.

Answer (score 2):

By the rank-nullity theorem, we have that the dimensions of the kernel of $ T $ and the image of $ T $ sum to 4. On the other hand, the kernel of $ T $ contains two linearly independent vectors, namely $ (1, 0, 0, 1) $ and $ (0, 1, 1, 0) $, so it has a minimum dimension of $ 2 $, which means that the image of $ T $ has maximum dimension 2, and cannot be all of $ \mathbb{R}^3 $. Therefore, $ T $ is not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the vector $$u=\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 1 \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}$$ and name $f$ the considered map.

If $f$ is surjective, then $\exists \begin{bmatrix} x  \\ y \\ z \\ t  \end{bmatrix}$ such as $f ( \begin{bmatrix} x  \\ y \\ z \\ t  \end{bmatrix} )= \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 1 \\ 1  \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow x-t=1,z-y=1 \Rightarrow x-t+2z-2y=-1 \neq1 $. It is absurd. So the map is not surjective.