# Showing surjectivity of a map.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Define a map $f:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$ by $f(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(a_1,a_3)$

I want to show $f$ is onto. So here is what I did

Suppose $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$. Now WLOG take $(x,0,y)\in \Bbb R^3$ this point under the map $f$ gives us $(x,y)$ hence onto. [For an arbitrary point $(x,y)$ in the co-domain I shown that it has a pre-image and in my perception this is what ontoness mean.]

But am I wrong? (I doubted my method cause I've seen [somewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774253/is-this-map-onto) on this site users use a complicated method to show a map is not onto).

Comment: Your solution is correct. I wouldn't use "WLOG" because to show that $f$ is onto, you need to find one pre-image for each value in the co-domain of $f$, not to find them all (which is also not difficult). The map in the link you attached is more complicated and so it takes more effort to show that it is onto.

Comment: Your map is of course onto. The other one you have linked is a totally different map.

Comment: All $(a_1,a_3)$ has infinitely many antecedents $(a_1,x,a_3)$

Comment: @DietrichBurde: For the linked problem,  $(x+t,2y-z,-x+2y-z+t,0)\in \Bbb R^4$ is a pre-image for an arbitrary point $(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3$. Isn't it?

Comment: @Sucre: No, it's not: the first component of that map is defined as $x-t$, which means "the first coordinate minus the fourth coordinate". If you subtract the fourth coordinate of your vector from the first one you get $(x+t)-0$ which is clearly not $x$, as you thought it would be. The same argument stands for the other components.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You have found a pre-image to every element of the co-domain, hence the map is onto.